# How to click an option displayed after rightclick using contextClick()?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have just started learning Selenium WebDriver. Was practicing on deemo site http://demo.automationtesting.in/WebTable.html 
Unable to select the Delete option after right clicking on Delete icon(under Actions column).Below is the code i tried, but it doesn't work.Please help.

```
WebElement del = driver4.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class=\"avddbl\"]/del-click/button/i)[1]"));
        ac.contextClick(del).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find the WebElement on the page and thought the right click items are not automatable. So posted the question. Today found the element on the page. Below is the code that works.

```
Actions ac = new Actions(driver4);
WebElement del = driver4.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class=\"avddbl\"]/del-click/button/i)[1]"));
//ac.contextClick(del).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
ac.contextClick(del).perform();
driver4.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[text()=\"Delete\"])[1]")).click();  
Alert al = driver4.switchTo().alert();
al.accept();
```

Thanks